# Mysterious Clojure function

Tags: clojure, declarative

I would like to write a clojure function that has the following behaviour :

```
  (take 4 (floyd))
  => '((1) (2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9 10))

  (take 3 (floyd))
  => '((1) (2 3) (4 5 6))

  (take 1 (floyd))
  => '((1)))
```

I tried using `partition` and `partition-all` to validate these tests however i couldn't get the right solution. If you have any idea of how to do it, i would really appreciate a little help. I started using clojure a few weeks ago and still have some issues.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a recursive solution? Post your attempts here please

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors, stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I tried ``` (defn f
  ([] (f (range)))
  ([s] (lazy-seq (cons (partition (take (first s) s) s)  (f (drop (first s) s))))))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible to solve it with `partition` / `partition-all`, since they split your sequence into predefined size chunks.

What you can do, is to employ recursive lazy function for that:

```
user> (defn floyd []
        (letfn [(f [n rng]
                  (cons (take n rng)
                        (lazy-seq (f (inc n) (drop n rng)))))]
          (f 1 (iterate inc 1))))
#'user/floyd

user> (take 1 (floyd))
;;=> ((1))

user> (take 2 (floyd))
;;=> ((1) (2 3))

user> (take 3 (floyd))
;;=> ((1) (2 3) (4 5 6))

user> (take 4 (floyd))
;;=> ((1) (2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9 10))
```

another variant can use similar approach, but only track chunk-start/chunk-size:

```
user> (defn floyd []
        (letfn [(f [n start]
                  (cons (range start (+ start n))
                        (lazy-seq (f (inc n) (+ start n)))))]
          (f 1 1)))
```

another approach is to use clojure's collection operating functions:

```
user> (defn floyd-2 []        
        (->> [1 1]
             (iterate (fn [[start n]]
                        [(+ n start) (inc n)]))
             (map (fn [[start n]] (range start (+ start n))))))
#'user/floyd-2

user> (take 4 (floyd-2))
;;=> ((1) (2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9 10))

user> (take 5 (floyd-2))
;;=> ((1) (2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9 10) (11 12 13 14 15))

user> (take 1 (floyd-2))
;;=> ((1))
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Clojure. I started learning it recently and laziness is a quite new concept to me. I was used to writting `cons` inside a `lazy-seq` . Thanks for helping me. I really appreciate this and it helps me a lot for my homework

Comment: The solution using the collection operating functions is quite elegant. The laziness is preserved without using `lazy-seq` . I get bonus points the more I use clojure built-in functions (only when there is a benefit to it)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

```
(defn floyd []
  (map (fn [lo n] (range lo (+ lo n 1))) 
       (reductions + 1 (iterate inc 1)) 
       (range)))

(take 5 (floyd))
;=> ((1) (2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9 10) (11 12 13 14 15))
```

This was arrived at based on the observation that you want a series of increasing ranges (the `(range)` argument to `map` is used to produce a sequence of increasingly longer ranges), each one starting from almost the triangular number sequence:

```
(take 5 (reductions + 0 (iterate inc 1)))
;=> (0 1 3 6 10)
```

If we start that sequence from `1` instead, we get the starting numbers in your desired sequence:

```
(take 5 (reductions + 1 (iterate inc 1)))
;=> (1 2 4 7 11)
```

If the `+ 1` inside the mapped function bothers you, you could do this instead:

```
(defn floyd []
  (map (fn [lo n] (range lo (+ lo n)))
       (reductions + 1 (iterate inc 1))
       (iterate inc 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew the `reductions` function. Your example is quite instructive.

Comment: By any chance, could you help me with a macro I try to write in Clojure?

Comment: First rule of macro club: don't write macros :) I don't answer many questions on StackOverflow. I focus most of my energy on the Clojurians Slack because I prefer the interactivity of a "chat" system.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```clj
(defn floyd []
  (map (fn[n]
         (let [start (/ (* n (inc n)) 2)]
           (range (inc start) (+ start n 2))))
       (iterate inc 0)))

(take 4 (floyd))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the way it is written. Never thought that it could be so compact and clear.

Comment: `(iterate inc 0)` is `(range)` and most likely less efficient at it.  Turning that into a `for` makes it even more compact: `(defn floyd []
  (for [n (range)
        :let [start (inc (/ (* n (inc n)) 2))]]
    (range start (inc (+ start n)))))
`